# Learning PDFBox; Trouble with Sample Code

Tags: java, ios, apache, import

I'm trying to learn how to use PDFBox and found some sample code that I'm working through [here](http://radixcode.com/pdfbox-example-code-how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-file-with-java/).

I've attached the code in the post-script.

When I compile the code in Dr. Java, I get the following error:

```
File: C:\Users\Dick Hurtz from Hold\Desktop\Java Programs\JavaStuff\PDFManager.java  [line: 30]
Error: The constructor org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser(org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile) is undefined
```

I'm not sure what to do about this, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Here are the classes:

***MAIN:***

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaPDFTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   PDFManager pdfManager = new PDFManager();
   pdfManager.setFilePath("E:\test.pdf");
   System.out.println(pdfManager.ToText());       

}    
}
```

***PDFManager:***

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class PDFManager {

private PDFParser parser;
private PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
private PDDocument pdDoc;
private COSDocument cosDoc;

private String Text;
private String filePath;
private File file;

public PDFManager() {

}
public String ToText() throws IOException
{
   this.pdfStripper = null;
   this.pdDoc = null;
   this.cosDoc = null;

   file = new File(filePath);
   parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file,"r")); // update for      PDFBox V 2.0

   parser.parse();
   cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
   pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
   pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
   pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();
   pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
   pdfStripper.setEndPage(10);

   // reading text from page 1 to 10
   // if you want to get text from full pdf file use this code
   // pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());

   Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
   return Text;
}

public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
}

}
```

Comment: Here is the line that gives the error:                

parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file,"r")); // update for PDFBox V 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the PDDocument directly using

```
PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(file);
```

is the recommended way to load a PDF document from a file.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make that adjustment.

Comment: Here is the line that gives the error:        parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file,"r")); // update for PDFBox V 2.0